# Azure Container Apps performance is slow, what might be causing it?

Tags: azure, containers

I've notice after deploying my ASP.NET Core API to an Azure Container App that it will sometimes be incredibly slow. Doing the same request many times to the same endpoint, most requests take 1-3 seconds, but occasionally there's like a dip, I don't know what causes it, there's no other traffic to this API and the requests can take anywhere from 25-45 seconds.

I thought it might be something like with Azure App Services where it can idle out, but I don't believe that happens with container apps.

Any ideas what could cause this? These are the settings for the container app:

- 1 - 10 Min/Max Replicas
- 0.25 CPU Core
- 0.5 memory (Gi)

Cpu Core usage never gets higher than 58.79M cores...

Things to note:

- The endpoint it hits, all it does is trigger an Ok response and thats it.
- It doesn't get these spikes of lag when run locally or in an Azure App Service. So I know it's an issue with the container itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have fixed it, I had 2x container images including the one they provide on startup (simple hello world). After deleting that and keeping only one it seems to have solved the issue. Not sure what's the cause of this but it's a work around.

Comment: Lewis are you referring to 2 containers in the registry? I have similar issues but only have 1 image

Comment: Yeah I had 2 container images when you press Edit & Deploy and it lists the container images.